# Parsing json data through alamofire in table view cells

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am trying to parse json data in my table view cell and its not parsing and not showing the cells . I am attaching all my code please tell me whats the mistake i am doing .. I am not getting any error but the cells are not showing. I have made separate class and functions for json parsing and storing it in an array .

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  WorkingFeed2
//
//  Created by keshu rai on 08/08/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 keshu rai. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource{

var post : PostData!
var posts = [PostData]()
typealias DownloadComplete = () -> ()

var arrayOfPostData : [String] = []
@IBOutlet weak var feedTable: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    feedTable.dataSource = self
    feedTable.delegate = self


}

 func downloadPostData(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
    Alamofire.request("https://new.example.com/api/posts/get_all_posts").responseJSON { response in
    let result = response.result
    if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

        if let successcode = dict["STATUS_CODE"] as? Int {
            if successcode == 1 {
                if let postsArray = dict["posts"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]
                {
               for obj in postsArray
                {
                        let post = PostData(postDict: obj)
                        self.posts.append(post)
                        print(obj)
                    }
//                        self.posts.remove(at: 0)
                    self.feedTable.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 419
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : ImageTableViewCell = self.feedTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contentViewReuse") as! ImageTableViewCell
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    print(post)
    cell.configureCell(post : post)
    return cell


}
}
```

This is my PostData Class.

```
import Foundation

 class PostData {
var _profileImageURL : String?
var _fullName : String?
var _location : String?
var _title : String?
var _postTime : String?
var _likes : Int?
var _comments : Int?
var _mediaType : String?
var _contentURL : String?
var _content : String?
var _plocation : String?

var profileImageURL : String
{
    if _profileImageURL == nil {
        _profileImageURL = ""
    }
    return _profileImageURL!
}

var fullName : String
{
    if _fullName == nil {
        _fullName = ""
    }
    return _fullName!
}
var location : String {
    if _location == nil {
        _location = ""
    }
    return _location!
}
var title : String {
    if _title == nil {
        _title = ""
    }
    return _title!
}

var postTime : String {
    if _postTime == nil {
        _postTime = ""
    }
    return _postTime!
}

var likes : Int {
    if _likes == nil {
        _likes = 0
    }
    return _likes!
}

var comments : Int {
    if _comments == nil {
        _comments = 0
    }
    return _comments!
}

var mediaType : String {
    if _mediaType == nil {
        _mediaType = ""
    }
    return _mediaType!
}

var contentURL : String {
    if _contentURL == nil {
        _contentURL = ""
    }
    return _contentURL!
}
var content : String {
    if _content == nil {
        _content = ""
    }
    return _content!
}
var pLocation : String {
    if _plocation == nil {
        _plocation = ""
    }
    return _plocation!
}






init(postDict : Dictionary<String , AnyObject>)
{
    if let postsArray = postDict["posts"] as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]
    {
        for i in 1..<postsArray.count
        {

            let fullName1 = postsArray[i]["full_name"] as? String
            self._fullName = fullName1


            let profileImageURL1 = postsArray[i]["profile_pic"] as? String
            self._profileImageURL = profileImageURL1

            let location1 = postsArray[i]["user_city"] as? String
            self._location = location1

            let title1 = postsArray[i]["title"] as? String
            self._title = title1

            let postTime1 = postsArray[i]["order_by_date"] as? String
            self._postTime = postTime1

            let likes1 = postsArray[i]["liked_count"] as? Int
            self._likes = likes1

            let comments1 = postsArray[i]["comment_count"] as? Int
            self._comments = comments1

            let mediaType1 = postsArray[i]["media_path"] as? String
            self._mediaType = mediaType1

            let contentURL1 = postsArray[i]["media_path"] as? String
            self._contentURL = contentURL1

            let content1 = postsArray[i]["content"] as? String
            self._content = content1

            let plocation1 = postsArray[i]["location"] as? String
            self._plocation = plocation1
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my PostDataTableViewCell code.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class PostDataTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {



@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titlePost: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var profileFullName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var profileUserLocation: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var likeBtn: UIButton!
var buttonAction: ( () -> Void) = {}


var pressed = false
@IBAction func likeBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if !pressed {
        let image = UIImage(named: "Like-1.png") as UIImage!
        likeBtn.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        pressed = true
    } else {

        let image = UIImage(named: "liked.png") as UIImage!
        likeBtn.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.15, y: 0.15)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,
                       delay: 0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 6.0,
                       options: .allowUserInteraction,
                       animations: { [weak self] in
                        self?.likeBtn.transform = .identity
            },
                       completion: nil)
        likeBtn.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        pressed = false
    }


}
@IBAction func commentBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Commented")

}
@IBAction func shareBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.buttonAction()


}
@IBAction func readContentBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Read")

}

@IBOutlet weak var contentPostLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var contentTypeView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var likeAndCommentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfLikes: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfComments: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var postLocation: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var postTimeOutlet: UILabel!


func configureCell(post : PostData)
{
    titlePost.text = "\(post.title)"
    profileFullName.text = "\(post.fullName)"
    profileUserLocation.text = "\(post.location)"
    numberOfLikes.text = "\(post.likes) Likes"
    numberOfComments.text = "\(post.comments) Comments"
    postLocation.text = "\(post.pLocation)"
    postTimeOutlet.text = "\(post.postTime)"
        let url = URL(string: post.profileImageURL)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    profileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    contentPostLabel.text = "\(post.content)"

    if post.mediaType == "image"
    {
    let url1 = URL(string: post.contentURL)
    let data1 = try? Data(contentsOf: url1!)
    let image = UIImage(data: data1!)
    let imageToView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    imageToView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375  , height: 250)
    imageToView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
    contentTypeView.addSubview(imageToView)


    }
    else if post.mediaType == "null"
    {
        print("Status")
    }
    else if post.mediaType == "video"
    {
      print("Video")
    }
    else if post.mediaType == "youtube"
    {
     print("youtube")
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Apart from the issue private backing variables for *pretending* being constants is ridiculous in Swift. Just use the `let` keyword.

Comment: @keshu Rai is call going within table functions ? And do you have data present in array at that time ? Use breakpoint and debug your code.

Comment: actually no .. the value is not getting store in the array .. i called the print function on array in viewdid load and it showed an empty error .. can u please go through the code and lemme know what error i am making .. please it woud help a lot as i am stuck in this code from very long .

Comment: downloadPostData() where did you called the function ???? I cant find in viewdidLoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the issue occurs because you are trying to parse the value for key `posts` **twice**, once in `PostData` and once in `ViewController`.

First of all in Swift 3 a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`, secondly – as already mentioned in my comment – private backing variables are nonsense in Swift.

The class `PostData` can be reduced to

```
class PostData {
    let profileImageURL : String
    let fullName : String
    let location : String
    let title : String
    let postTime : String
    let likes : Int
    let comments : Int
    let mediaType : String
    let contentURL : String
    let content : String
    let plocation : String


    init(postDict : [String:Any])
    {           
        fullName = postDict["full_name"] as? String ?? ""
        profileImageURL = postDict["profile_pic"] as? String ?? ""
        location = postDict["user_city"] as? String ?? ""
        title = postDict["title"] as? String ?? ""
        postTime = postDict["order_by_date"] as? String ?? ""
        likes = postDict["liked_count"] as? Int ?? 0
        comments = postDict["comment_count"] as? Int ?? 0
        mediaType = postDict["media_path"] as? String ?? ""
        contentURL = postDict["media_path"] as? String ?? ""
        content = postDict["content"] as? String ?? ""
        plocation = postDict["location"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude that was helpful .. now i am getting the data in my cells thanks a lot ... but i am not getting the images that i have passed inside the view.  in configureCell() function in my PostDataTableViewCell code. any solution for that ?

Comment: Basically loading data synchronously is bad. You should add the image property in the model and use a caching system. In your code the image is reloaded again and again when the user scrolls. And don't use String Interpolation `"\()"` for strings. That's redundant.

Comment: actully m just a fresher .. m in learning stage .. wud surely improve my code :) thanks